# Change base color in sencha touch for themes other than the default theme

Tags: colors, sencha-touch, themes

I'm unable to change the base color of themes other than the default theme. 
For ex: I can't change the base color of windows theme from black to any other color I want. 
Can somebody please tell me how to change that?

I used the $base-color variable in app.scss

Please note that I tried using $base-color variable above and also below the import lines.
Also, there is no compile error after compiling it using compass.
And yeah, it's working with the default theme of sencha.